# Bootstrap 3 row breaks on medium devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with differently sized divs. I'd like to have and row that displays 3 column wide divs on medium & large displays and 6 column wide divs on small devices.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Lots of stuff</div>
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Less stuff</div>
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Whooa!</div>
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">More stuff</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

on medium & large displays this looks like:

```
–––––––––––––––––   –––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––
| Lots of stuff |   |   Less stuff  |   |   Whooa!     |   |  More stuff  |
|               |   –––––––––––––––––   |              |   |              |
|               |                       ––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––
|               |
–––––––––––––––––
```

which is just great. but on small displays it looks like:

```
–––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––– 
| Lots of stuff |   |   Less stuff  |
|               |   ––––––––––––––––– 
|               |   ––––––––––––––––
|               |   |    Whooa!    |
–––––––––––––––––   |              |
                    ––––––––––––––––                       
––––––––––––––––
|  More stuff  |
|              |
––––––––––––––––
```

which is quite far from this pretty picture i have in my mind:

```
–––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––– 
| Lots of stuff |   |   Less stuff  |
|               |   ––––––––––––––––– 
|               |
|               |
–––––––––––––––––
–––––––––––––––––   ––––––––––––––––– 
|    Whooa!     |   |  More stuff   |
|               |   |               |
–––––––––––––––––   –––––––––––––––––
```

Easy solution would be to give these divs an minimum height but that is not really an option in this case.

Please help!

edit: added fiddle http://bootply.com/81952

Comment: You can **wrap** those pair `divs` separately.  I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you explain why min-height is not an option? I think that's your only choice: http://bootply.com/81954

Comment: to make the website customer-proof. customer will be editing texts heavily over time and fixing one min-height is not going to work.

Comment: Oh man, I wouldn't want to be in your shoes. I've had this problem before and I think it might not even be possible. Check this link though: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Not sure if this is compatible with Bootstrap. Why it's so hard to make divs use 100% of the available vertical space is beyond me, really.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Bootstrap 3 way is as follows:

In between your second and third div, add the following bit of HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

See working example here: http://bootply.com/81970.

Documation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping those pair `divs` separately.  somewhat like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="inner1"> -------------------------------------------
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Lots of stuff</div> |
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Less stuff</div>    |
</div>----------------------------------------------------------
<div class="inner2"> -------------------------------------------    
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">Whooa!</div>        |
    <div class="service col-sm-6 col-md-3">More stuff</div>    |
</div>----------------------------------------------------------
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: actually, wrapping them on pair of divs, bootstrap style, did the trick. http://bootply.com/81967 thank you!